# Django: Problem with Adding Editing and Deleting Functionality in Django Form with TemplateView

Tags: python, django

I am learning Django by building an application, called TravelBuddies. It will allow travelers to plan their trip and keep associated travel items (such as bookings, tickets, copy of passport, insurance information, etc), as well as create alerts for daily activities. The application will also able to update local information such as weather or daily news to the traveler. Travelers can also share the travel information with someone or have someone to collaborate with them to plan for the trip.

I have created a form that enables the users to add their trip information, like trip name, planner name, co-planner, date etc. However, I can't find a proper way of allowing them to edit and delete the forms. I have seen some videos. But they are not using TemplateView like me. So, I am a bit confused.

Here are my codes in `forms.py` file under **addtrip** folder:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.forms import ModelForm
from trips.models import Trip

class TripForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Trip
        fields = ['trip_name', 'date', 'planner_name', 'add_coplanner', 'trip_description']

class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password']
```

Here are my codes in `views.py` file under **addtrip** folder:

```
from django.contrib.auth import mixins, authenticate, login
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from .forms import TripForm, UserForm
from trips.models import Trip
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse

# Create your views here.


class AddTripFormView(mixins.LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
    login_url = 'login/'
    template_name = 'addtrip/addtripform.html'

    def get(self, request):
        form = TripForm()
        trips = Trip.objects.all()
        args = {'form': form, 'trips': trips}
        return render(request, self.template_name, args)

    def post(self, request):
        form = TripForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            trip_name = form.cleaned_data['trip_name']
            date = form.cleaned_data['date']
            planner_name = form.cleaned_data['planner_name']
            trip_description = form.cleaned_data['trip_description']
            args = {'form': form, 'trip name': trip_name, 'date': date, 'planner name': planner_name, 'trip description': trip_description}
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('trips:triplist'))

class AddUserFormView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'addtrip/registrationform.html'

    # Display blank form
    def get(self, request):
        form = UserForm()
        args = {'form': form}
        return render(request, self.template_name, args)

    # Process form data
    def post(self, request):
        form = UserForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            user.set_password(password)
            user.save()
            # return user object if credentials are correct
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                if user.is_active:
                    login(request, user)
                    return redirect('addtrip:login')

        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
```

Here are my codes in `urls.py` file under **addtrip** folder:

```
from . import views
from django.urls import path
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

app_name = 'addtrip'

urlpatterns = [
    path('addtrip/', views.AddTripFormView.as_view(), name='addtrip'),
    path('register/', views.AddUserFormView.as_view(), name='register'),
    # login
    path('addtrip/login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='addtrip/login.html'), name='login'),
    # logout
    path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),
]
```

Here are my codes in `addtripform.html` file inside the **templates** folder:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block title %} Add Trip {% endblock %}

{% block content %}

<div class="container">
    <h2>Add New Trip</h2>
    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Here are my codes in `models.py` inside **trips** folder:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models

class Trip(models.Model):
    trip_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date = models.DateField()
    planner_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    add_coplanner = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    trip_description = models.CharField(max_length=1000, default='null')
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=150, default='null')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.trip_name

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.trip_name)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)


class Activity(models.Model):
    trip = models.ForeignKey(Trip, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    activity_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date = models.DateField()
    time = models.TimeField()
    location = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    activity_description = models.CharField(max_length=1000, default='null')
    item_type = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    item_number = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    add_cotraveller = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=150, default='null')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.activity_name

    def save(self):
        super(Activity, self).save()
        self.slug = '%i-%s' % (
            self.id, slugify(self.trip.trip_name)
        )
        super(Activity, self).save()
```

Here are my codes in `urls.py` inside **trips** folder:

```
from . import views
from django.urls import path

app_name = 'trips'

urlpatterns = [
    path('triplist/', views.TripListView.as_view(), name='triplist'),
    path('triplist/<slug:slug>/', views.ActivityView.as_view(), name='activity'),
    path('tripapi/', views.TripApiView.as_view()),
    path('tripapi/<int:pk>/', views.TripDetailApiView.as_view()),
]
```

How can I add the edit and delete functionalities in the form? Is it possible to to add the edit and delete functionalities with the TemplateView by using functions like `def update(self, request):` and `def delete(self, request):`?

Answer (score 0):

What you need are [generic editing views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#). These include `FormView`s, `CreateView`s, `UpdateViews`, and `DeleteViews`. Add in `ListView`s and `DetailView`s and you have got 95% of the views you need for a project basically half-built for you.

Comment: Is it possible to to add the edit and delete functionalities with the TemplateView by using functions like `def update(self, request):` and `def delete(self, request):`?

Comment: Can you explain why you would add methods to do this?

Comment: I would add the methods to update and delete the form.

Comment: What I mean is "why would you reinvent the wheel?". Its more rhetorical than anything. You should be using generic views for this task.

Comment: Please read the documentation in the link I gave you. There is a reason other people were using the generic views in the videos.

Comment: OK. Would you please share me with the working codes `FormView`, `CreateView`, `UpdateView` and `DeleteView`. I am a beginner. So, that will be really helpful.